# Determine if thread has been started

Tags: python, multithreading

How to determine if a python thread has been started? There is a method `is_alive()` but this is true **before** and **while** a thread is running.

Comment: `return self.__started.is_set() and not self.__stopped` should return false before started. 'Just before method start' from doc str mean then `__started` is set but thread is not running yet (very short period of time i think)

Answer (score 9):

You can look at the **ident** field of the **Thread** instance.  The [Python 2.7 documentation for Threading](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread) describes **ident** as

> The ‘thread identifier’ of this thread or None if the thread has not
>   been started.

Answer (score 3):

Use `isAlive` (or `is_alive`) `Thread` class method.

Python 2.7 http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/threading.py#l995

```
def isAlive(self):
    """Return whether the thread is alive.

    This method returns True just before the run() method starts until just
    after the run() method terminates. The module function enumerate()
    returns a list of all alive threads.

    """
    assert self.__initialized, "Thread.__init__() not called"
    return self.__started.is_set() and not self.__stopped
```

Python 3 https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/threading.py

```
def is_alive(self):
    """Return whether the thread is alive.
    This method returns True just before the run() method starts until just
    after the run() method terminates. The module function enumerate()
    returns a list of all alive threads.
    """
    assert self._initialized, "Thread.__init__() not called"
    if self._is_stopped or not self._started.is_set():
        return False
    self._wait_for_tstate_lock(False)
    return not self._is_stopped
```

Answer (score 1):

You could have the thread function set a boolean flag on startup, and then check that flag.

Comment: That's not exactly what I'm looking for. There is always a delay between a thread is started and when it's executed. I want to avoid this glitch between. A possibility would be to overload `Thread.start` and set a flag.

Comment: @Razer You can't generally avoid the delay between a thread being started and when it's actually executed and any design that relies on such a thing is by definition broken. Anyhow, you really shouldn't have to need such a flag - what's your *actual* problem you're trying to solve?